# Set console video resolution with KMS

Tags: linux

I search over Google results and it seems to be impossible, so: Anyone knows how to change or set to an specific video resolution in console using KMS?

I'm not using any graphic server or graphic sub-system, so this question is only regarding to the console.

I'm using an Arch box with Intel video card, KMS driver with KMS enabled, gummiboot (for UEFI boot process) and all properly configured.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding video=800x600@75 (or what resolution you need) to /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX or GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter.
In my case:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet video=1152x864@75"
and update grub2 configuration (update-grub in Debian, grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg (from root user) in Fedora/CentOS/RHEL).
If using grub-legacy just add video=800x600@75 to kernel options in /boot/grub/menu.lst:

```
title  Arch Linux  
root   (hd0,0)  
kernel /boot/vmlinuz26 root=/dev/sda1 ro video=800x600@75  
initrd /boot/kernel26.img
```

Found the answer here: [Changing console resolution on systems with KMS (Kernel Mode Setting)](https://github.com/venator85/kb/wiki/Changing-console-resolution-on-systems-with-KMS-%28Kernel-Mode-Setting%29)

for gummiboot (now systemd-boot) you'll need to edit /loader/entries/arch.conf on EFI system partition.
esp/loader/entries/arch.conf:

```
title   Arch Linux  
linux   /vmlinuz-linux  
initrd  /intel-ucode.img  
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img  
options root=LABEL=arch_os rw video=800x600@75
```

[systemd-boot - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot#Configuration)